# Rebuilding RAID1 in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, software-raid, raid1, disaster-recovery, ubuntu-9.10

I had my second HD in my RAID1 come up with bad sectors.  So I got another drive and pulled out the bad sector drive and put the new drive in.  With the original working RAID1 drive in the computer it failed to boot.

I manually copied everything from the old drive over via a Gparted Live CD.  Still no booting.

Kind of scratching my head here as I can see that both of the drives have data on them but are unable to get either of them to boot.  I used  a Ubuntu live CD and couldn't even manually mount either of the drives, which I thought was really the odd part.

Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: If I turn on the swap spaces of both drives via the live CD the available swap space shows up as the total of the two drives.

Comment: Please elaborate on 'failed to boot'.  Do you get a black screen, do you see the boot loader, do you get errors, do you get a message about missing operating system.

Comment: When booting up the system it holds up at "Verifying DMI Pool Data ........." forever.

Comment: how long did you wait at that point?

Answer (score 1):

The drive that failed was probably the one that had the bootsector written to it.  Try booting with the live CD, mount your assembled RAID 1 root partition under `/mnt`, your boot partition under `/mnt/boot` (if you have a separate boot partition) then run `chroot /mnt grub-install hd0`.

Comment: Both the drives appear to have MBR partition tables on them, according to the info from Palimpsest as well both having the BOOT Flag displayed in Gparted.

When I look at the RAID itself from a Live CD via Palimpsest both of the drives have a "-" in the State column, and I am unable to ADD drive to the RAID or create a new RAID.

The RAID shows up as a Drive when looking at it in the browser but I was not able to get it to mount properly.

Answer (score 0):

When I was initially making a RAID-1 on Ubuntu 9 a couple of years ago, when I was testing failures I ran into something like this:

- I had a working 2-disk RAID-1 array
- I powered off the machine and unplugged the drive cable from one drive
- Powered up.

When I did this, the boot would hang (it's been two years so I can't remember exactly where).  Eventually (at least 5 minutes, maybe 10 or 15 minutes) it would drop me into the initramfs shell.  At that point I could run `mdadm` to get the array going and finish booting.

By contrast, if I did the following:

- Working 2-disk RAID-1 array
- With machine up, run `mdadm` to fail and remove a drive.
- Power down, unplug that drive.
- Powered up.

the system would boot fine.  Turns out there was a "bug" (I put it in quotes because IIRC there was a lot of arguing about the pros and cons in bugzilla) that Ubuntu is by default in a mode where it will not auto-assemble a degraded array.  And if your root partition lives on that array you can't boot (though eventually you'll be dumped into the initramfs shell).